# Navigation drawer issues action bar hidden, navigation items click is not working and image item background changed

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have created Slide menu with navigation drawer, action bar hidden on main activity, items are not clickable and navigation item images not visible correctly. attaching images and code below.

This is how it looks

[image]

How it should be(in iOS)

[image]

navigation added in main_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="?attr/colorButtonNormal"

    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"/>


    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/viewBgr"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"
        />
```

nav_header.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/statusBar"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    android:layout_height="100dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ABC"
        android:textColor="@color/viewBgr"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

drawer_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view"
    >

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_nightmode"
            android:icon="@drawable/theme"
            android:title="Theme"/>
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_touch"
            android:icon="@drawable/fingerprint"

            android:title="Touch Id"/>
    </group>

    <item android:title="Cmmunicate">
        <menu>
            <item android:id="@+id/nav_contact"
                android:icon="@drawable/contact_us"

                android:title="Contact Us"/>
            <item android:id="@+id/nav_notification"
                android:icon="@drawable/notification"
                android:title="Notification"/>
            <item android:id="@+id/nav_userguide"
                android:icon="@drawable/user_guide"
                android:title="User Guide"/>
            <item android:id="@+id/logout"
                android:icon="@drawable/logout"
                android:title="Logout"/>

        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

created another styles.xml with v24 api and added to the Android Manifest file with no action bar to the particular activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

MainActivity.java

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        navigationView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.navigation));


        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
```

action added in the same class find the below method

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">


           .....


        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_dashboard" // APP_BAR
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_dashboard"
            app:itemIconTint="@drawable/drawer_item"
            app:itemTextColor="@drawable/drawer_item"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_dashboard_drawer" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

According to this xml you have to changes in java class also.

If this will not work please let me know in comment.

**EDIT:**

**app_bar_dashboard:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="ai.gramboard.app.activity.DashboardActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/content_dashboard"/>  //include here content xml 

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: What is there in app_bar_dashboard, getting error for drawer item and activity_dashboard_drawer. Can you please elaborate I am new to android

Comment: Bit difficult understand, kindly elaborate

Comment: @OhStack first xml belongs to activity of navigation and second belongs to app bar

Comment: Working but action bar hidden

Comment: you can check the first image on top same like that